# Этимология слова "слово"

Tags: этимология

В [старославянской библии](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/e_dzherela_Biblia_2006/e_dzherela_Biblia_2006.pdf) слово "слово" используется в следующем контексте:

"И да сътвориши слово судное, дело пестрящего..." Исх.28:15 page 144
https://www.bibleonline.ru/bible/rus/02/28/#15;

"И възметъ ааронъ имена сыновъ израилевъ, на слове суднемъ..." Исх.28:29 page 145
https://www.bibleonline.ru/bible/rus/02/28/#29;

Как это можно объяснить этимологически?

Comment: 1) не понятно, где у вас цитаты начинаются и кончаются. 2) на что эти предложения соответсвуют в современном русском языке?

Comment: @qdinar 1) исправил 2) Исх.36:15, Лев.8:8

Comment: где это тут: http://www.patriarchia.ru/bible/ex/36/ ? тут 15-й стих такой: "длиною покрывало тридцать локтей, и шириною покрывало четыре локтя: одиннадцати покрывалам мера одна." - не сходится.

Comment: @qdinar чего-то в русском переводе и вправду нет, можете посмотреть два последних примера, а с другими постараюсь разобраться (надо будет посмотреть на других языках, а то может в синодальном переводе это просто "подчистили")

Comment: По месту упомянутого слова в Библии всюду значится слово НАПЕРСНИК = нагрудник, принадлежность облачения ветхозаветного священника.

Answer (score -1):

*Слово* имеет смысловую морфему **лов**.
*Ловля, ловкость, улов, отлов*.
Значение - у*лав*ливать образ

Отголоски сохранились в древнерусских словах *словити, словлю* в значении, *славить (почитать)* и *(с)ловить (поймать)*. http://oldrusdict.ru/dict.html#

Самоназвание славян так же имеет две версии происхождения опирающиеся на этот корень и с этими же значениями https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD
От *slovo= Часто этимологию самоназвания связывают со словом слово. Таким образом, словѣне — люди, говорящие «словами» (то есть «по-нашему»). Сравнительно с этим название неславянского (то есть иноязычных племён) — нѣмьци «немые». Аналогичного происхождения самоназвание албанцев — shqiptarët («говорящие понятно»). Кроме того, в значении «народ» употреблялось слово ѩзыкъ («язык»).

От *slava По другой версии, этимология самоназвания восходит к слава. Таким образом самоназвание «славяне» — это «славные», «знаменитые люди», то есть люди, о которых слышно, о которых говорит молва, о которых идет слава. Эта точка зрения, популярная в XVI—XIX веках, ныне фактически не имеет приверженцев среди лингвистов; общеславянской является именно огласовка с -о-, в то время как огласовка с -а- является результатом вторичного сближения со словом слава с XVI—XVII вв. и под некоторым влиянием греческого и латыни.

Если допускать, что слово произошло от греческого  λόγος то непонятно откуда оно взялось в самоназвании славян до встречи с греками, зато объяснимо для древних охотников, которые жили с лова.